# SQL Function Debugging

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am trying to create a sql function that will return first name from the full name column. Right now it is returning the last name in the format Last,First. It is suppose to return the First name after the ,

My substring function is suppose to start grabbing the information at @index+2, but it is starting from the beginning. I am not sure what is wrong?

```
Create Function dbo.fnGetFirstName (@fullname varchar(100))
Returns Varchar(50)
AS
Begin
--declare the local variable: firstName
Declare @fn varchar(50);
--declare the index variable to find the index of the separator that separates last name from first name
Declare @index int;
--get the separator index value
SET @index = CHARINDEX(',',@fullname);
--check if the default separator (,) exists
IF @index > 0
--if it does, use the substring function to find the First name
BEGIN 
    Set @fn = SUBSTRING(@fullname, @index+2, LEN(@fullname)-@index);

END
```

Comment: it seems there is a missing END

Comment: It was a missing end. Thanks for the Tip. Cant believe I missed That.....

Comment: I think it works fine: http://rextester.com/ISBH13610

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an End to finish the Function

Answer (score 0):

Create Function dbo.fnGetFirstName (@fullname varchar(100))
Returns Varchar(50)
AS
Begin
--declare the local variable: firstName
Declare @fn varchar(50);
--declare the index variable to find the index of the separator that separates last name from first name
Declare @index int;
--get the separator index value
SET @index = CHARINDEX(',',@fullname);
--check if the default separator (,) exists
IF @index > 0
--if it does, use the substring function to find the First name
BEGIN 
    Set @fn = SUBSTRING(@fullname, @index+2, LEN(@fullname)-@index);
END
return @fn
END